# NullPointerException - AutoCompleteTextView in a dialog

Tags: android, nullpointerexception

I want to put an AutoCompleteTextView in a dialog.

```
private void VerificaCompatibilitaPublic() {
    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(this);
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_priv, null);
    Button check = view.findViewById(R.id.btn_test);

    AutoCompleteTextView texttest = (AutoCompleteTextView) view.findViewById(R.id.actv);
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, COUNTRIES);
    texttest.setAdapter(adapter);

    AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
            .setView(view)
            .create();

    check.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            //do something
        }
    });

    alertDialog.show();
}
```

I get the error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.AutoCompleteTextView.setAdapter(android.widget.ListAdapter)' on a null object reference
```

I tried also to move the AutoCompleteTextView after the "setView" method, but I always get the NullPointerException

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution by myself.
Since the code is correct, I searched over my files and I found that the custom dialog XML file was splitted also in v28.

I deleted the v28 XML file and everything is working.

Answer (score -2):

Before you go into the solution, you must ensure you are mapping your views correctly if so, then your code is good but missing this line

**Whats Missing**

```
adapter.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown);
```

this line sets the dropdown view to your adapter, as you need a layout for your to autocomplete text view,

**After adding the missing code**

```
texttest.setAdapter(adapter);
```

I hope this will resolve the issue.

Comment: This is not solving my issue. I still get the NullPointException

Comment: you are inflating the dialog wrong, and mapping the views in that dialog